# restructuredtext TOC subgroups

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs, toctree

I'm trying to get a TOC with subgroups pointing to different rst files. This is my index.rst:

```````
.. bonobo-trans documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Fri Feb  8 18:09:07 2019.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

Transformations
---------------

- :doc:`source/source`
- :doc:`source/target`
- :doc:`source/lookup`
- :doc:`source/sequencer`
- :doc:`source/sorter`
- :doc:`source/aggregator`

Source
``````
Target
``````
Lookup
``````

Requirements
------------
- bonobo 0.6.3
- pandas
- sqlalchemy

Installation
------------

Install bonobo-trans by running:

    pip install bonobo-trans

Contribute
----------

- Issue Tracker: github.com/$project/$project/issues
- Source Code: github.com/$project/$project

Support
-------

If you are having issues, please let me know.

License
-------

The project is licensed under the Apache license.
```````

I have added three subheadings to illustrate how I need it to look, but I only want a list of links under the "Transformation" section. Basically this is how it should end up like:

[image: example]

Is this possible??

Answer (score 0):

This is an option that should get you closer is to use the `:hidden:` option for `toctree`. However, you will not get a collapseable section or references to heading on the same page.

```
Transformations
---------------

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1
   :includehidden:

   sequencer
   sorter
   aggregator

.. toctree::
   :hidden:

   source
   target
   lookup

Requirements
------------
- bonobo 0.6.3
- pandas
- sqlalchemy

Installation
------------
...
```

Also note that files are just referenced by their name in the TOC, eliminating the need to use `:doc:`. Also all document references are assumed to be contained with the `source` directory, provided it is so configured in `conf.py`.